# How to give counter back to GUI from worker process with as little blocking of worker as possible and as little busy wait for gui as possible?

Tags: python, performance, tkinter, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have a gui that starts two seperate programms (that can be run parallel) in seperate processes.
I want to update the collective progess bar while the programms are running. So far i've been doing it through two multiprocessing.Variables (one for each worker process). After each successful iteration a worker process gets the lock for its multiprocessing.Variable and increments the counter (the Variable is a counter of type int in both cases).
The gui is busy looping - in the loop the gui is trying to access (get lock) for multiprocessing.Variable1 and read the value and then for multiprocessing.Variable2 and read its value. If the gui read a new value then the progress bar is updated.

Measures to increase "performance". After the gui read each counter it is going to sleep for a bit to have less busy wait (it doesn't matter that much if the progress bar doesn't count up one for one but jumps a little from time to time). The worker processes are acquiring the lock with a timeout so that they are blocked as little as possible (in case the gui is reading the value currently and thus blocking any write).
Any suggestions how to go about this to get as little slow_down and cpu-usage increase as possible by the progress bar?

Edit: My goal is not to make the gui reactive even when the two worker processes are running. The programm is already doing what i want. I only want to make it more performant (the progress bar is not supposed to slow down the workers and not supposed to use up a lot of cpu-time while waiting for changed results from the workers)

Answer (score 0):

you need your "user event" to spawn a worker thread, this way your main thread can continue running the GUI eventloop.

the worker thread starts the other process and waits for its result. then in order to update the GUI from another thread you need to call `tk.after(0, update_function, args)` which executes the function in your main thread which is where you should update the GUI.

the following example illustrates the point.

```
import tkinter
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time
import tkinter.ttk

def process_worker_task(multiproc_queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
    try:
        for i in range(11):
            multiproc_queue.put(i*10)
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        multiproc_queue.put(None)

def thread_worker_task():
    global current_number
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_worker_task, args=(queue,), daemon=True)
    process.start()
    while True:
        result = queue.get()
        if result is not None:
            tk.after(0, update_bar, result)
        else:
            break
    process.join()
    tk.after(0, lambda: button.configure(state='normal'))  # enable button

def update_bar(number: int):
    variable.set(number)
    

def start_worker_thread():
    button.configure(state='disabled')  # disable button
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_worker_task, daemon=True)
    thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tk = tkinter.Tk()
    current_number = 0
    button = tkinter.Button(tk,text="do stuff", command=start_worker_thread)
    button.pack()
    variable = tkinter.DoubleVar(tk,value=0.0)
    progress_bar = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(variable=variable)
    progress_bar.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

if you have more than 1 worker you could have them all use the same queue

```
import tkinter
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time
import tkinter.ttk

def process_worker_task(multiproc_queue: multiprocessing.Queue, workerId: int):
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            multiproc_queue.put((workerId, i))
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        multiproc_queue.put(None)

def thread_worker_task():
    global current_number
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_worker_task, args=(queue, 1), daemon=True)
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_worker_task, args=(queue, 2), daemon=True)

    process1_progress = 0
    process2_progress = 0
    Nones_received = 0
    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    while True:
        result = queue.get()
        if result is None:
            Nones_received += 1
            if Nones_received == 2:
                break
        else:
            if result[0] == 1:
                process1_progress += 1
            else:
                process2_progress += 1
            tk.after(0, update_bar, (process1_progress + process2_progress) / 2 * 10)
    process1.join()
    process2.join()
    tk.after(0, lambda: button.configure(state='normal'))  # enable button

def update_bar(number: int):
    variable.set(number)
    

def start_worker_thread():
    button.configure(state='disabled')  # disable button
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_worker_task, daemon=True)
    thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tk = tkinter.Tk()
    current_number = 0
    button = tkinter.Button(tk,text="do stuff", command=start_worker_thread)
    button.pack()
    variable = tkinter.DoubleVar(tk,value=0.0)
    progress_bar = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(variable=variable)
    progress_bar.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much -  I did't know that you could instruct the main-thread to update from within another thread (very useful in the future) - in my case however the user doesnt need to interact with the gui while the progressbar is running over the screen. The reason i did not want the gui (main-thread) to busy wait is because it would use up cpu-performance. Is there a way to make the gui (main-thread) sleep until any of the two Value (counters) change? I am updating the progressbar with progressbar.update(). Your solution would not make the application more performant (time, cpu)

Comment: @Yoshl you never want to busy-wait, instead you want to deactivate the button when the work starts and reactivate it later when the task ends, sleeping stops redraws and resizing, etc, which just makes the OS think your app is not responding, as for performance this app consumes `0.1%` of the cpu in all 3 threads (mostly because the OS is rounding it up), so you shouldn't try saving extra performance.

Comment: @Yoshl i have updated the answer to show how to disable and enable the button.

Comment: @Yoshl also when writing GUI code you want to use a lot of `try: finally:` when you want things to happen whether or not a task is successful, such as enabling buttons, orelse your buttons could remain disabled when an exception happens.

Comment: @Yoshl if you have a big GUI with a lot of buttons which need to be disabled you should look into using custom tkinter events, which can be application wide, you could have an event that just disables all buttons and another which just enables all buttons.

Comment: @Yoshl another approach which apps employ is to use a modal toplevel that just contains the progress bar, this way the user can't interact with the rest of the GUI while the work is being done.

Comment: Can you edit your solution, so that there are two processes being created and the thread waiting for the results needs to wait for two queues (one for each process). Or would you create two waiting threads in that case? - by the way: can you create a chat-room for us, so that we can talk without filling up the comments? (i dont know how and might not have enough reputation)

Comment: @Yoshl i'd just have them both putting data on the same queue, and the worker thread would wait for 2 `None` instead of only 1, and each worker would send back a tuple specifying its `id` and its `payload`, if your returns are small enough you shouldn't have any synchronization delays, but if you are very cautious of blocking the workers for a few microseconds (which you shouldn't if you're writing python anyway) you could have 2 extra threads merging the 2 multiprocessing queues into a single `queue.Queue`.

Comment: @Yoshl also i updated the answer with what i mean, same `0.1%` cpu load.

Comment: Thank you - i understand now that a single Queue ist probably the easiest solution while still very fast. But i am curious: what If i had a lot more worker processes that needed to talk back to the main process/thread very offen. Wouldn't the possibility of one process blocking another be a lot higher with only one queue? What approach would you take then? You mentioned that one could have a queue and a thread for each worker. The thread would sort the results of the respective worker into a communal queue - is that the best/industry standard approach in this situation?

Comment: @Yoshl if your application is doing any notable work then you shouldn't worry about the queue being the bottleneck, this approach is used by python and qt's implementations of worker pools, it is generally good, unless you are shoving tens of thousands of updates every second into the queue, in which case splitting the queue into multiple queues can help, but smarter solutions like pushing updates to the queue less frequently would be much more efficient,  after all monitors are only expected to work at 60 fps, and pushing over 60 updates every second is pointless.

Comment: @Yoshl if you are in a situation where you require tens of thousands of updates every second you probably want to rewrite the whole thing in c++ with lock free structures and no extra processes to avoid IPC altogether.